# Cannot install ANY PACKAGE in R (MAC OS Mojave)

Tags: r

```
ld: library not found for -lintl
clang-4.0: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [sourcetools.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘sourcetools’
 * removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/3.5/site-library/sourcetools’
```

I am reading online that a solution may be in modyfing the "Makevar" file from R.

Could you please help me? I cannot work without R!

Luca

Comment: Try this installer: https://github.com/coatless/r-macos-rtools/blob/master/README.md

Comment: I tried to installed it but the installation failed 

Comment: SOLVED!!!!
I followed this guide here:
https://github.com/adamhsparks/setup_macOS_for_R

Suggestion, if during the makevar manipulation you are not able to modify it, use nano in sudo:

sudo nano ~/.R/Makevars